# (iPhoneX) White spaces in top and bottom of the screen when running Camera

Tags: ios, swift, camera, qr-code, iphone-x

I've made an app that worked fine on my iPhone 6 Plus. The app contains a QRCode scanning feature which obviously starts the camera. When running the Camera, it works in full screen with my iPhone 6 Plus but not in my iPhone X. the camera still works but there are white bars above and below the camera view. Any tips?

here's the code of the scanner:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import SafariServices

class Attend: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var border: UIImageView!

var video = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let session = AVCaptureSession()

    let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

    do
    {
        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
        session.addInput(input)
    }

    catch
    {
        print ("ERROR")
    }

    let output = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
    session.addOutput(output)

    output.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)

    output.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]

    video = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
    video.frame = view.layer.bounds
    view.layer.addSublayer(video)

    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: border)

    session.startRunning()


}


func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    if metadataObjects != nil && metadataObjects.count != 0
    {
        if let object = metadataObjects[0] as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
        {
            if object.type == AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode
            {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "QR Code", message: object.stringValue, preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Retake", style: .default, handler: nil))
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Open", style: .default, handler: { (nil) in
                    UIPasteboard.general.string = object.stringValue
                    self.loadSafari(url: object.stringValue)
                }))
                present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
        }
    }

}


func loadSafari(url : String){
    guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }

    let safariController = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
    present(safariController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}




}
```

Comment: Those white area is know as safe Margins, self.view will not pass beyond those area, you don't want to end up in your view hidden behind sensor bar or bottom line.

Comment: Thank you for replying.
but I only want the camera to run in full screen. I don't mind the sensor bar part.

Comment: you can try adding in UIApplicationWindow

Comment: I tried adding that in the swift file but I got an error saying undeclared type

Answer (score 0):

1 - use LaunchSceen.storyboard instead of launch images - your bottom cut problem will be solved
2 - make your top constraints from safe area of your view